# How to download this video

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet, download

http://37signals.com.nyud.net:8080/images/svn_posts/photoshop_mockup.mov.

it's a 30 mb video but when i start downloading it's finished under 1 mb every time. What is the problem ?

Comment: DRM, most likely...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nyud.net is a [swarm cache](http://www.coralcdn.org/). Remove that part of the hostname and the port, and try again in order to get it from the original source.

Comment: ok going to try

Comment: ok now download has gone over 1 mb will inform you if it will download fully.